# Who is responsible for configuring transport security on managed wide area networks?

Tags: tls, router

If there is a router within a wide area network managed by an ISP, who is responsible for managing transport layer security? The owner of the router, or the ISP managing the WAN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Transport Layer Security (TLS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) workas at layer 5 (session) and 6 (Presentation) of the [OSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) model.

Typically, an ISP will only manage layer 1 (physical) to 3 (network), sometimes providing some layer 4 (transport) related functions (like filtering).

Therefore, it is typically not the ISP responsibility to handle TLS.

**HOWEVER** You're describing the relationship between a customer and a service company. Such a relationship is governed by two things: local laws (first) and a business contract (second). Both will vary widely so that is typically the documents you need to refer to when trying to answer this type of questions.

Comment: Great, I think what I was really trying to clarify was whether encryption was the responsibility of the organisation or the ISP. I gather most organisations configure their own routers and assign their own certificates. Thanks

Comment: Routers are, basically, acting at layer 1 to 2 as well: that isn't usually where TLS is implemented either (although it isn't uncommon so see gateway devices with more capability deployed in small to medium environment: some integrated security products cover all OSI layers, including application firewalling and will implement TLS. But that's more of a special case).

Comment: It turns out in this particular situation, the service carrier was contracted to provide the certificates and transport layer security. While the router was owned by the organisation, it did not configure it and contracted the ISP to do this.